# Other name for "Predeterminer"/"Noun Premodifier" Dependency Relation?

Tags: computational-linguistics, parsing, dependency-grammar

I'm [reading a paper](https://www.pnas.org/content/117/48/30046) which makes use of word dependency relationships from the Stanford Dependencies (SD) list.

One such relation they refer to as "Predeterminer" and "Noun Premodifer". A few examples of this relation are shown below:
[image]

However I can't find any mention of this relationship type in the papers which supposedly characterize the list of Stanford Dependencies:

1. [Generating Typed Dependency Parses from Phrase Structure Parses](https://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/LREC06_dependencies.pdf)
2. [Universal Stanford Dependencies: A cross-linguistic typology](https://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/USD_LREC14_paper_camera_ready.pdf)

These mention several dozen relationships, but not that one. I'm sure it's being referred to by some other name, and I simply am not recognizing it due to my lack of classic linguistics training.

So my question is: Is there some other name for this relation they're calling "Predeterminer"/"Noun Premodifer" that is used elsewhere?

Thanks!

Comment: So I realized that this figure actually comes from [another paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.04341.pdf). In that paper they refer to this as the `det` (Determiner) relation. But I thought `det` was much more narrowly defined?

Comment: Determiners determine, predeterminers modify.